# my dog is over weight

Tags: dogs

My dog is over weight, a 39 lb spayed female Beagle.  If I have food, she will bark and throw a tantrum, lying on the floor putting her paws over her eyes and basically crying until I say "OK I will give you some if you wait" she then quiets down and waits quietly, I then give her a portion of my food when I'm done. She's not that fat but everyone says she is chunky and it is my fault. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Pet stores have many brands of low-calorie dog foods (they typically say they are for older dogs, or less active dogs, rather than having "low-calorie" in the name). You need to stop feeding her people food, or at least cut it *way* down. You also need to ensure that she gets plenty of exercise.

The best thing is to go to a vet, who can tell you how much she should weigh, recommend a low-calorie dog food, and tell you exactly how much food to give her each day.